# Пропадает заголовок запроса

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net-core

Отправляю запрос с заголовком Autorization. Если смотреть данные о запросе через кастомный middleware, то он там есть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее дело доходит до контроллера

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetUserData")]
public string GetUserData()
{
    return HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Type=="Email").Value;
}
```

И тут уже заголовок вместе с Claims куда-то пропадает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По какой причине данные о запросе исчезают, пока доходят до контроллера?

Метод Configure выглядит следующим образом:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {              
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseAuthentication();
    //MyMiddleware в этом не причастен, пробовал его убирать
    app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: Свойства какого объекта указаны на рисунке?

Comment: @V-Mor `HttpContext` на обоих

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заметил, что хоть и отправляю запрос протоколом http на порт 5000, в контроллере HttpContext.Request.Scheme имеет значение https. Покопался и нашел причину.

По стандарту Параметры веб сервера в свойствах проекта имеют следующий вид:

> https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000

Если же все протоколы здесь привести к одному виду (либо http либо https), то данные о запросе не пропадают и доходят до контроллера. Не знаю, почему так, но буду благодарен, если кто-то объяснит сие явление.